# Implementing Normal Mapping HLSL

Tags: graphics, 3d, hlsl, directx-11

So, ok. I'm trying to implement normal mapping in my small game engine and I just cannot get it to work.

When I do the lighting with only per-vertex normals everything is fine, but if I try to do it with normal map then everything falls apart.

I know I have the right UVs because the texture looks good, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong when it comes to Normal Map texture.

This is some of my code in my pixel shader(HLSL)....

```
    float3 NormalSample(float3 normalMapSample, float3 unitNormalW, float3 tangentW)
{
    //Uncompress each component from [0,1] to [-1,1]
    float3 normalT = 2.0f*normalMapSample - 1.0f;
    // Build orthonormal basis.
    float3 N = unitNormalW;
    float3 T = normalize(tangentW - dot(tangentW, N)*N);
    float3 B = cross(N, T);

    float3x3 TBN = float3x3(T, B, N);

    // Transform from tangent space to world space.
    float3 bumpedNormalW = mul(normalT, TBN);

    return bumpedNormalW;
}
```

Any ideas on what I can be doing wrong?

Comment: The code looks right. Make sure you calculate normal and tangent correctly. Also keep in mind that NormalSample returns normal in the world space, so you should do the lighting in the world space. What happens if you set normalMapSample to a fixed value (0.5, 0.5, 1) instead of sampling the texture?

Comment: Ok, I'm actually implementing my lighting using a different lighting model and will give updates on this. I think what I'm doing wrong right now is that I'm not properly transforming vectors between tangent space, world-space, and model-space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I fixed it. I was just doing the normal calculations in the wrong coordinate space. To make it easier I decided to do everything in model-space. It looks great. Too bad I'm not allowed to post screen shots.

Thanks again Miloszmaki....